# Gene expression Table to Expression Matrix converstion

Tags: rna-seq, gene-expression, format-conversion

I have an RNAseq gene expression file (Count data) as follows, I need to conduct a Differential gene expression analysis between Patients, for that, I need to have this file as a Matrix of Rows as Genes and columns as counts (samples), how best can I get this as matrix file?

Thanks a lot for your help, Stay safe

[image: My data looks like the following]

Comment: Cross posted here:

https://www.biostars.org/p/471641/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question stated differently is as follows:

> I have data in long format and need to change it to wide format. For that, I want to keep the `gene_raw`, use `patient_id` for the column names and `gene_code` for the row names. How can I do this easily?

Assuming you know how to read that into R as a data.frame that I'll call `d`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
reformatted = d %>% select(patient_id, gene_code, gene_raw) %>% spread(patient_id, gene_raw) %>% column_to_rownames(gene_code)
```

Or something along those lines.